# Setear texto resultante en una etiqueta P

Tags: javascript, promesas

Tengo el resultado de una promesa que si ejecuto esto me saca por consola elresultado que quiero:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(localStorage.getItem('address')).then(
    console.log
);
```

Pero cuando trato de meter el valor en una etiqueta P no me aparece nada. Como debo montar esta sentencia bien?

```
web3.eth.getBalance(localStorage.getItem('address')).then(
    $('#balance').text()
);
```

Answer (score 3):

Las promesas esperan una función como primer parámetro, en el primer ejemplo con el `console.log` le estas pasando una función, en el segundo con el `$('#balance').text()` le estas pasando el resultado de la ejecución de una función, que puede o no ser una función, en este caso no lo es. 
Lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
web3.eth.getBalance(localStorage.getItem('address')).then(function(text){
  $('#balance').text(text)
});
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio de grán ayuda ;D